# Combining two dataframes using same column names in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe named df_1 with following columns,

| ID | Name | Age | City |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jaz | 25 | D |
| 2 | Sam | 28 | E |

And another dataframe named df_2 with following columns,

| ID | Name | City |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | Alex | F |
| 5 | Abi | E |

I want a resultant df as follow,

| ID | Name | Age | City |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jaz | 25 | D |
| 2 | Sam | 28 | E |
| 4 | Alex | NA | F |
| 5 | Abi | NA | E |

How to get this using R?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(df_1, df_2)
```

Output:

```
  ID Name Age City
1  1  Jaz  25    D
2  2  Sam  28    E
3  4 Alex  NA    F
4  5  Abi  NA    E
```

#### Data

```
df_1 <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2),
                   Name = c("Jaz", "Sam"),
                   Age = c(25,28),
                   City = c("D", "E"))

df_2 <- data.frame(ID = c(4,5),
                   Name = c("Alex", "Abi"),
                   City = c("F", "E"))
```